# Convert stringstream macro to function

Tags: c++

I have a macro that looks something like this:

```
#define LOG_MESSAGE(message, level) { std::stringstream _s; _s << message; Singleton->LogMessage(_s.str().c_str(), level, __FILE__, __LINE__); }
```

and can be called like this:

```
LOG_MESSAGE("Name: " << name", ENUM::WARNING);
```

I would like to convert it to a function instead, maybe something like

```
void LogMessage(const char* const message, const char* const file, int line)
{

}
```

The problem is that you would have to call this function like so:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Name: " << name;
LogMessage(s.str().c_str(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

I want something along the lines of:

```
LogMessage("Name: " << name, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Is there any way to make this a one liner like the macro? How would I go about using the stream << operator with a function? Is there a clever way I could use a template or override the operator with a class?

**I do not have access to c++ 11**

Comment: While I appreciate the advice, I was told this should be in a method. So whether it is the correct decision or not is currently irrelevant.

Comment: The point of macro is to copy-paste code everywhere without caring about if it's valid syntax.
Functions don't copy-paste the code of their arguments, they evaluate them.
Unfortunately, what you want to do seems impossible.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but both modern C++ and C++03 still need the preprocessor for some tasks. You should always try to avoid macros when a language feature does the same job, but here you don't seem to have a choice

Comment: This might seem slightly irrelevant, but I really must stress that the body of this kind of macro should *always* be `do{...}while(0)` instead of `{...}`.

Comment: @marsh The do{...}while(0) format consumes the trailing semicolon when you say LOG(data);    Without it using log like so: if(error)LOG(message); else doSomethingElse();  won't compile.  [I'll ignore the "always use braces argument.  You still have an extra null statement even if you use braces.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here is an example

```
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

void LogMessage(const std::basic_ostream<char>& ss, const char* const file, int line)
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << file << "(" << line << "): " << static_cast<const std::stringstream&>(ss).str();
    OutputDebugStringA(ss1.str().c_str());
}

int main()
{
    LogMessage(std::stringstream() << "Hello," << " World! " << 5, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, to save some typing in each logging line:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

class Logger
{
    std::stringstream _ss;
    std::string _file;
    int _line;
public:
    Logger(const char* const file, int line)
    {
        _file = file;
        _line = line;
    }
    ~Logger()
    {
        std::stringstream ss1;
        ss1 << _file << "(" << _line << "): " << _ss.str();
        OutputDebugStringA(ss1.str().c_str());
    }
    template<typename T>
    Logger& operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        _ss << value;
        return *this;
    }
};

#define LOG Logger(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    // approach 1: with a macro, saving from typing of __FILE__ and __LINE__ each time
    LOG << "Hello," << " World! " << 6;
    // approach 2: without a macro, but with typing of __FILE__ and __LINE__ each time
    Logger(__FILE__, __LINE__) << "Hello," << " World! " << 7;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for those free-function `operator<<` overloads taking a stream by reference on the LHS. `LOG` is much better but is a macro, as the OP is trying to avoid. Also I suggest streaming `.rdbuf()` rather than copying the entire log buffer. And drop that Windows crap.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, (I assume it's about the 1st code example) why do you think it does not work for `operator<<` overloads taking a stream by reference on the LHS? The second code example shows both the options with and without macro. "Windows crap" is just an example of final logging destination, of course it can be replaced in particular implementation.

Comment: The class is probably what the reviewer was referring to, thank you very much. Though I am not sure that I am going to switch it over now. I guess I have some thinking to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically, no.**

The macro is the traditional workaround, so I'm not sure why you're trying to dump it!

Comment: Not that it matters but it came up in a code review.

Comment: @marsh: Bizarre. I guess your colleague/boss is one of those "abide by a mantra" "hate all macros always" types, with no regard for context. A shame! That being said, it's hard to come up with a solid counter-argument against such people when being coerced into taking a `printf`-style approach instead. At least this can be done in a type-safe manner nowadays, using variadic templates, though, honestly, total overkill.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to have `"Name: "` as a string and add `message` to it and then use the `c_str()` method of the combined string.

```
LogMessage((string("Name: ") + message).c_str(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Good trick, Though not quite what I am looking for, also I plan to use it with ints, objects etc. Just like a normal stringstream could.